# Playwright: Download via Print to PDF?

Tags: automation, download, playwright, headless-browser, playwright-python

I'm seeking to scrape a web page using Playwright.

I load the page, and click the download button with Playwright successfully. This brings up a print dialog box with a printer selected.

[image: print dialog box]

I would like to select "Save as PDF" and then click the "Save" button.

Here's my current code:

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    playwright_page = browser.new_page()
    got_error = False

    try:
        playwright_page.goto(url_to_start_from)
        print(playwright_page.title())
        html = playwright_page.content()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Playwright exception: {e}")
        got_error = True

    if not got_error:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

        #download pdf
        with playwright_page.expect_download() as download_info:
            playwright_page.locator("text=download").click()

        download = download_info.value
        path = download.path()
        download.save_as(DOWNLOADED_PDF_FOLDER)

    browser.close()
```

Is there a way to do this using Playwright?

Comment: Okay, yes, you are right. I had `headless= False` so I could see what was going on. But I'm not sure yet what you have in mind by "the one command line print to PDF outport".  I set `headless= True` and `playwright_page.locator("text= download").click()` times out waiting for event "download". Could you please post the lines of code you have in mind, as an answer? I can then implement them and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable enough about this subject, to grasp what you are trying to communicate. I don't know how to enter the browser via Playwright. If you could post a few lines of code, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I've added more of my existing code to the original post. Possibly someone here who has worked with Playwright can provide sample code to accomplish this. In the meantime I will research along the lines you have recommended.

Comment: @KJ,  your advice to `set headless = True` was very helpful. Since there's supposed to be no UI in headless mode, Chrome doesn't even create a print dialog. There were other glitches that kept me from getting it working initially, but I got those resolved now. Please post your advice in the form of an answer, and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Okay. Well if you just post an answer saying something like, "you won't get a print dialog if you use headless=True", I would mark that as accepted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks very much to @KJ in the comments, who suggested that with `headless=True`, Chromium won't even put up a print dialog box in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need the print dialog, you can generate this directly from Playwright by emulating the media type.

```ts
  await page.emulateMedia({ media: "print" });
  await page.goto("https://robstarbuck.uk/cv");

  await page.pdf({ path: "./cv.pdf", format: "A4" });
```

This is how I generate my CV.

[Playwright - Media Emulation](https://playwright.dev/docs/emulation#color-scheme-and-media)

[Playwright - PDF](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-pdf)