Playwright to automate a browser action and need to open the print dialog pressing `Ctrl+P` key does not seem to work
Hi we are opening the new page and trying to perform Ctrl+P keyboard action on the new page, code is attached below
(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://example.com');

    // Simulate Ctrl+P to open the print dialog
    await page.keyboard.down('Control'); 
    await page.keyboard.press('P');
    await page.keyboard.up('Control');

    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);

    await browser.close();
})();

we are not able to achieve this, can we accomplish this in Playwright and any example code available,
please help us solve this issue; and can save this printed pdf in local file
I am trying to handle the printer pop-up box

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72324669/playwright-download-via-print-to-pdf or use build-in class https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-pdf

Keyboard actions automate the page, not the browser. Why do you need to open the print dialog in particular? I would just use page.pdf() if you're trying to create a PDF.
